# convert text field to a date/time field in access query not working

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

I'm working with a access database and vb6. My table has a field named "InvoiceDate" which is a text field. I'm not allowed to make database modifications. So I guess my only option is to change the text field into a date/time field in my query. I found several methods to do so. They are as follows.

- Format(InvoiceDate, "yyyy/mm/dd")
- (DateSerial(Left(InvoiceDate,4),Mid(InvoiceDate,5,2),Right(InvoiceDate,2)) 
    Between #2015/01/01# And #2016/01/01#))
- DateValue(InvoiceDate, "yyyy/mm/dd")
- CDate(InvoiceDate, "yyyy/mm/dd")

But those 4 methods didn't work. I can't figure out this.

The query I'm using as follows

```
SELECT Invoice.InvoiceDate, InvoicedProduct.InvoiceType, Invoice.InvoiceStatus, 
    Invoice.RetailerID, Invoice.DailySalesID, Invoice.RepID, 
    InvoicedProduct.Quantity, InvoicedProduct.UnitRate, 
    InvoicedProduct.TotalItemValue 
FROM Invoice 
INNER JOIN InvoicedProduct 
ON (Invoice.DailySalesID = InvoicedProduct.DailySalesID) 
    AND (Invoice.RepID = InvoicedProduct.RepID) 
    AND (Invoice.InvoiceID = InvoicedProduct.InvoiceID) 
WHERE (((InvoicedProduct.ProductID)='9010001174130.4') 
    AND (DateValue(Invoice.InvoiceDate) Between #2015/01/01# And #2016/01/01#)) 
GROUP BY Invoice.InvoiceDate, InvoicedProduct.InvoiceType, Invoice.InvoiceStatus, 
    Invoice.RetailerID, Invoice.DailySalesID, Invoice.RepID, 
    InvoicedProduct.Quantity, InvoicedProduct.UnitRate, 
    InvoicedProduct.TotalItemValue 
HAVING (((InvoicedProduct.InvoiceType)='Invoice' OR (InvoicedProduct.InvoiceType)='Sound') 
    AND ((Invoice.InvoiceStatus)='VALID')) 
ORDER BY Invoice.InvoiceDate;
```

This gives me the error "Data Type mismatch in criteria expression"

Following two types are include in my InvoiceDate Field

2016/01/04 10:00: AM   and   2016/01/20 08:25 PM

The only difference is the colon after the time

[image: Following two types are include in my InvoiceDate Field]

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Eh... Share the content of that field. Also, option 1, 3 and 4 are nonsense. `Format` casts a date to a string, not the other way around, and `CDate` and `DateValue` only take one argument.

Comment: Erik von Asmuth, Please see the edited question sir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your criteria:

```
DateValue(Invoice.InvoiceDate) Between #2015/01/01# And #2016/01/01#
```

is correct, so the error message indicates, that one or more of your text dates in *InvoiceDate* don't represent a valid date, like 2015-06-31 or Null.

Run a query to check this:

```
Select *, IsDate(InvoiceDate) As ValidDate From Invoice
```

and see if any of the values of *ValidDate* are False.

To ignore the extra colon:

```
DateValue(Replace(Invoice.InvoiceDate, ": ", " ")) Between #2015/01/01# And #2016/01/01#
```

Comment: I found that the field has invalid date strings by running your query. It seems like that should be the error. Thank you.

Comment: OK. Added to the answer a possible way around the extra colon.

Comment: Gustav, I edited the question with my table. but i thought those are the valid dates. Then Again I'm wrong. That final cure worked. Thanks in advance sir. You saved the day

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback.